Applicability of van Holten's algorithm for symmetries in classical mechanics
Background
van Holten's algorithm (see e.g. here and here) is a way of constructing or recognizing dynamical/hidden symmetries in classical mechanics by looking for Killing tensors on the configuration space $M$
For the case of a particle of charge $q$ in an electromagnetic field, we have a Hamiltonian
$$ H = \frac{1}{2} g^{ij}(\mathbf{x}) \Pi_i \Pi_j + V(\mathbf{x}) $$
where

$g_{ij}(\mathbf{x})$ is the metric on the configuration space $M$ (whose co-tangent bundle $T^{*}M$ is the symplectic manifold that is the phase space of the system), which in general depends on $\mathbf{x}$,

$V(\mathbf{x})$ is the potential energy of the system, which depends only on the position in configuration space $\mathbf{x}$

$\Pi_{i} = p_i - qA_i$ are the kinematic/gauge invariant momenta, as opposed to the canonical momenta $p_i$

$A_i$ is the vector potential, $\nabla \times \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B}$.


The standard Poisson brackets are modified to
$$ \{ x^i, x^j \} = 0 \quad \{ x^i, \Pi_j \} = \delta^i_j \quad \{ \Pi_i, \Pi_j \} = q F_{ij} $$
where $F_{ij} = \frac{\partial A_j}{\partial q^i} - \frac{\partial A_i}{\partial q^j}$ is the (magnetic) field strength tensor.
Via Noether's theorem, a continuous symmetry of the system is associated with a charge $Q$, which is a constant of motion when Hamilton's equations are satisfied. This is equivalent to the Poisson bracket with the Hamiltonian vanishing:
$$ \{ Q, H \} = 0 $$
van Holten demonstrates that if this charge $Q$ can be expanded in the momenta $\Pi_i$ as
$$ Q = \sum_{k=0}^N \frac{1}{k!} C^{i_1 \dots i_k}(\mathbf{q}) \, \Pi_{i_1} \dots \Pi_{i_k} $$
where the coefficients $C^{i_1 \dots i_k} = C^{(i_1 \dots i_k)}$ are fully symmetric under exchange of any pair of indices, then if for some $p < N$, we have an expansion coefficient satisfying the relation
$$ \nabla^{(i_{p+1}} C^{i_1 \dots i_p)} = 0 $$
then the momentum expansion of $Q$ terminates at order $p$. Here $\nabla$ is the covariant derivative associated with the Levi-Civita connection constructed from $g_{ij}(\mathbf{x})$. The above relation generalizes the Killing condition for vector fields on $M$ to higher rank tensors -- hence $C^{i_1 \dots i_p}$ is known as a Killing tensor (or more accurately, are the coefficients of such a tensor).
To see this, plug the above momentum expansion of $Q$ into $\{Q,H\}= 0$. After some manipulation (e.g. using the metric compatibility condition $\nabla_i g_{jk} =0$), we find that requiring terms to vanish order-by-order in $\Pi_i$ yields
$$ C^i \frac{\partial V}{\partial x^i}= 0  $$
$$ \partial_iC  = q F_{ij} C^j  + C_i^{~j}  \frac{\partial V}{\partial x^j} $$
$$ \nabla_iC_j + \nabla_j C_i = q \left(F_{ik}C^{~k}_l + F_{lm} C_i^m\right) + C_{il}^k \frac{\partial V(x)}{\partial x^i} $$
$$ \nabla_iC_{jk} + \nabla_j C_{ki}  + \nabla_k C_{ij}  = q \left(F_{im}C^{~~m}_{ij} + F_{lm} C_{ij}^{~~m} + F_{jm}C_{il}^{~~m}\right) + C_{ijl}^{~~~m} \frac{\partial V(x)}{\partial x^m} $$
and so on. The $r$-th order term in this series of constraint relates the (derivative of) $r$-th order coefficients $C^{i_1 \dots i_r}$, to the $r+1$th order $C^{i_1 \dots i_{r+1}}$ and the $r+2$-th order $C^{i_1 \dots i_{r+2}}$, and so if the $p$-th order coefficient is a Killing tensor, then the $p+1$ and $p+2$ order coefficients must vanish as the potential $V(\mathbf{x})$ and field strength $F_{ij}$ are arbitrary.
If the rank of the Killing tensor is greater than one, we call the symmetry associated $Q$ a /dynamical/ or /hidden/ symmetry. If the rank is one (i.e. we have a Killing vector), and we satisfy another consistency condition, then $Q$ is associated with a /kinematic/ symmetry. An example of the latter is angular momentum in rotationally invariant systems, while an example of the former is the Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector in the 3d Kepler problem.
QUESTION
In the references listed above, there is no consideration of a system in the absence of an (electro-)magnetic field, i.e. $F_{ij}=0$, $A_i =0$. Does the series of recurrence relations still allow us to terminate the expansion of $Q$ at finite order?
I would think not, as the vanishing of the field strength and vector potential mean the canonical and kinematic momenta coincide. The corresponding expansion of $Q$ and order-by-order constraints required by the vanishing of the Poisson bracket mean that $r$-th order term relates only the $r$-th order and $r+2$-th order terms, so if $C^{i_1 \dots i_p}$ is a Killing tensor only the higher order coefficients whose rank is $p+2, p+4, p+6 \dots$ are forced to vanish.
But this would seem to limit van Holten's algorithm to a particular class of system. Is their a way to see that this is not the case, i.e. the Killing tensor condition and truncation of the $Q$ expansion works for a wider class of systems?
